# Database and Application how to integrate for deployment

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, deployment

So I have a big question to ask:

How do I make a Java application (using eclipse) use a database that will pack it into the jar file, or how do I get the database to ship with the jar file, without having to install a mysql server such as phpMyAdmin, workbench, etc?

I have an application that uses a database, now how do I extract that database and the application, so that it I can compile it into an exe file, and copy that one installer file, and when I install the application on another machine, I dont need to install a phpMyAdmin, mysql server, etc to run the database, and jdk for the program to run and all these unnecessary programs that the end user will NOT DO.

Please advise on how to do this, and best possible solutions.

This is also what I need to do to finish off my major project for the year for school (Grade 11).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: Another embedded database option is h2. It plays nicer with Java and has an emulation mode for MySQL.

Comment: *"so that it I can compile it into an exe file"*  The EXE file is a bad idea you should give up now.  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.  BTW - is the DB 'read only' or is the user intended to be able to update it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The user must be able to update it

Comment: *"jdk for the program to run"*  Very few apps. require a JDK, most just require a JRE.  The best way to ensure a JRE is present is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).

Comment: *"The user must be able to update it"*  Then an embedded DB (which is read-only) will not fit the requirement.  JWS has the ability to ensure an installer (e.g. for a DB) is called the first time the application is launched.  If the users can be trusted to 'click OK when prompted', that is probably a good way to go.

Comment: BTW - 'Grade 11' in Australia is the 2nd last year of high school.  Is it the same in S.A.?

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, We first have Primary school (Grade 1-7), then we have high school (Grade 8 - 12, grade 12 is also called matric) and then we have University/College where we get our degree.